# this.next() error in Meteor Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, iron-router

Getting a strange error in Meteor:

Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

and none of the content is rendering. How can I fix this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Here's my router.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
});

Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/user/:_username', {
  name: 'user_profile',
  data: function() { return Meteor.user();} 
});

Router.route('/create', function() {
  this.render('create_event');
});

Router.route('/events/:name', {
  name: 'event',
  data: function() { return Events.findOne({name: this.params.name});}
});



Router.route('/useremail', function() {
    this.render('userEmail');
}, {
    name: 'userEmail'
});

Router._filters = {
  hasCompletedProfile: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (user && ! userProfileComplete(user)){
      this.render('userEmail');
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  },
};

filters = Router._filters;
Router.onBeforeAction(filters.hasCompletedProfile);
```

Comment: this.next() has to be called always, just put it in your _filters method in last line outside of if block

Comment: Where exactly? Tried a few of the different spots in the _filters method but not working as of yet... Thanks though

Comment: In hasCompletedProfile function last statement must be this.next(), without this else block - even if you render something you still need to call this.next()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always call `this.next();` in your `Router._filters` method and not just on a condition.

Try replace your `Router._filters` method with this:

```
Router._filters = {
  hasCompletedProfile: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (user && ! userProfileComplete(user)){
      this.render('userEmail');
    }
    this.next();  // Take note, it is no longer in an else statement
  },
};
```